# JavaScript inside PHP Header Location

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to have a JavaScript function as a PHP header location?

```
$exit_location = "javascript:niftyplayer('niftyPlayer1').loadAndPlay('$directory$val')";

header("Location: $exit_location");
```

I asked around in IRC but I didn't get any definitive responses.

Comment: No it's not, and why would you.

Comment: Well, I have a list of media files on my server. When you click on one of them, the hit counter gets updated in my mysql database, and once the counter gets updated I wanted that file to play in the media player. Is there a better way of implementing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) appears to say that you can't use a `javascript:` URI, but the point of that URI scheme is to provide some JavaScript that generates a document, not that manipulates the current one.

> Well, I have a list of media files on my server. When you click on one of them, the hit counter gets updated in my mysql database, and once the counter gets updated I wanted that file to play in the media player.

Put the JavaScript in the page. Replace `$directory$val` with the URL that holds your re-directer.